# IE innerText is not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, innertext

I have a snippet like this in my HTML.

```
 <div class="scripts" style:"display:none">
 Test.settings = { width: 1050,
                   onready: function(object) { Test.objects = Test.objects || []; Test.objects.push(object); },
                   authenticationCredentials: {username: "name", password: "password"},
                   splashScreen:{background:false},
                   widgets:{sidebar: false}};
 Test.create('Test', 'http://192.168.5.80', Test.settings);
 dosomething = function(value){ 
 object=Test.objects[0];object.removeuseragentstylesheet('header');
 object.removeuseragentstylesheet('background');
 alert('Foo');
 if(!value){return;}
 var url = "app/controller/handler";
 var params = "&amp;idn=" + value; 
 Myajax.doPost(url,
               params,
               function(json){object=Test.objects[0];object.removeuseragentstylesheet('header');object.removeuseragentstylesheet('background');
               console.log(json);
               var result = JSON.parse(json);
               value = '@page{background-image: url("' + value + '"); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 2.5cm 2.5cm;}'
               if(result){
               object.adduseragentstyles(background, 'print', 'background');
               object.adduseragentstyles(result['letterhead'], 'print', 'header');
               }});}
</div>
```

When I do `document.getElementsByClassName("scripts")[0].innerText` I don't get the desired result in `IE 11`. It truncates lot of characters. Tried html escaping this as well but that also didn't yield any result. I observed that removing `alert('Foo');` or making `removeuseragentstylesheet` as `remove` seems to work! Can anyone tell me whats going on?

Comment: Try using `textContent` instead of the non-standard `innerText` perhaps, might work more predictably in IE.

Comment: I tried both just to make sure that I am not being stupid!

Comment: Here is a test fiddle for you https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/spLmfc4s/

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle, did know you could do that! For some reason this is not opening in my Virtual IE, due to some network problem, is this reproducible for you?

Comment: What is not opening? I do not have IE here (OSX)

Comment: The fiddle link is not opening from my IE Box. I could see it in Chrome but the issue doesn't exist there. So if you were validating the fiddle in IE, I thought I could confirm that the issue exists in the fiddle. Its not a problem. I will fix the network and check it.